# Find revision number for a tag

Tags: svn, repository

Perusing http://svn.osafoundation.org/chandler/tags/ I wanted to get the revision number for these tags. How can I do it? The only thing I can see is the most recent revision number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see "revision graph" in tortoise SVN, or, if you see the log and uncheck "stop on copy", you will see from which revision the tag was copied.

Comment: By your suggestion I looked with Tortoise SVN in "Repository Browser" and got what I needed. I'm not sure if that's the same as the "revision graph" you mentioned, but I'll mark it as correct since it took me where I wanted :). Thanks.